# How old is this tree

Tags: identification, trees, plant-health, tree-care

I’ve got a wattle that I was told only lives a couple of years. Wondering if it’s possible to tell it’s current age and how much life it has remaining? There’s a two story high house behind, to give an idea of height.

[image]
[image]

Comment: It is difficult from such photo. You need to get pictures of trunk, and of branches from trunk (so from "inside".  In any case I would say: less than 10 years, possibly around 5 to 7 years. Where do you live? (the climate and region could help to get better estimates).

Comment: I live in Melbourne, Australia. Can’t get more photos now. I believe  it’s a type of wattle, but don’t know which one exactly.

Answer (score 2):

I agree it could be 7 to 10 years old, I had one in a botanical garden that we cared for and was that size at 8-9 years.  It looks like a very happy shrub.  Here are some facts about the *Acacia pycnantha*:

- **Habit:** evergreen shrub less than 2 m tall or shrub or small tree less than 5 m tall, can be multi-stemmed from or near ground level
- **Longevity:  short-lived less than 15 years**
- **Growth rate:** fast
- **Coppicing ability:** nil or negligible
- **Root system:** shallow and spreading, fixes nitrogen via root symbiotic
- **Erosion control potential:** excellent for clayey sites or excellent for sandy sites